# NET matrix problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Let S denote the set of all the prime numbers p with the property that the matrix 
$$
\begin{matrix}
\left[
\begin{array}\\
        91 & 31 & 0 \\
        29 & 31 & 0 \\
        79 & 23 & 59 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\end{matrix}
$$
has an inverse in the field $$ \frac{Z}{pZ} $$. Then the set S=?

Answer (score 4):

A matrix has an inverse iff its determinant is not $0$ in the field.

You can compute this determinant from the 3rd column getting

$59(93\cdot 31 - 31 \cdot 29)=59 \cdot 31 \cdot 2^6$

This number is equivalent to $0$ if and only if we are in $\mathbb Z_2$, $\mathbb Z_{31}$ and $\mathbb Z_{59}$,

so $S$ contains every prime except $2$, $31$ and $59$.

Comment: Your first expression *obviously* has $59$ as a factor!